# how do I bind a function for each element my own function iterates over?

Tags: jquery, html

Basically, if this is my code:

```
jQuery.fn.createSelector = function(){
   return this.hide()
   .after('<div class="newElement"></div>');
   // bind'em !
   $(".newElement").click(function(){
      alert('test');
   });
};
```

The function returns the element (inserts it into HTML), but does **not** bind the click event on it. I need to bind various events on each element my function has inserted, but I don't know how :( google doesn't really help either.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're returning before the bind is executed. Just rearrange and you got it:

```
var $newElement = $('<div class="newElement"></div>');
$newElement.click(yourFunc);
return this.hide().after($newElement);
```

Your current code has another potential problem: it binds the click event to *every* `.newElement` on the page, so each time you call it, all previously created `.newElement`s would be bound again. This might be what you want to do, but it seems unusual so I thought I'd mention it.

There is a simpler way to do this -- maybe. Check out jQuery's [live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) function. Might not work for every situation, but it can be a big help. Instead of having to bind every time you create a `.newElement`, you can just say "all `.newElements` should execute this code when you click them." Declarative event binding for the win:

```
//Put this somewhere in your init function (or wherever)
$('.newElement').live('click', function()
{
    alert("Neat stuff");
});
```

And then your `createSelector` body would just be:

```
return this.hide().after('<div class="newElement"></div>');
```

And the event is automatically, passively "bound" to it.

Comment: "Declarative event binding for the win" +1

Comment: actually, you discovered my next problem, but I need exactly the opposite situation. using my function i'm iterating over all ``<select>`` tags and replacing them with my own custom select divs. and with click on each of those divs, I need to open a list of ``options`` for each ``select``, so I need to bind the clicks uniquely = select1 opens list1, select2 opens list2, etc. and I can't find out how :(

Comment: @RiMMER: There are a few ways to do that (I think I understand what you're trying to do), but the solutions are complex enough that I can't describe them in a comment. If you can't figure it out, it merits a question of its own. I will just say as a word of warning that creating a new jQuery function is relatively advanced, and, unless you're making an extension meant to be used over and over (perfectly likely) there are simpler ways to do what you've described.

Answer (score 2):

Your function is adding the new element and then immediately returning, all before `.click()` is called, so the handler is never bound.

Return the element(s) you invoke `.createSelector()` on *after* binding to the new element:

```
jQuery.fn.createSelector = function() {
   this.hide().after('<div class="newElement"></div>');

   $(".newElement").click(function() {
      alert('test');
   });

   return this;
};
```